# Find the matrix $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a given unitary matrix then if there exists a non zero matrix $B$ so that $A+B$ is an unitary matrix then $B$ needs to satisfy the equation $A^*B+B^*A+B^*B=0$. How to find the matrix $B$ which satisfy this equation?

Comment: Let $C$ be any other unitary matrix and let $B=C-A$. Have you missed some condition?

Comment: This is the updated question.

Comment: There are still many matrices satisfying this equation, and you can still use the comment by @LordSharktheUnknown : If $A\neq I$, you can choose $B=I-A$. If $A=I$, choose $B=-I-A$

Comment: Find all the matrices $B$ that satisfies $A^∗B+B^∗A+B^∗B=0$

Answer (score 0):

Lord Shark the Unknown had it in his comment; if $U \ne A$ is *any* other unitary,

$U^\dagger U = U U^\dagger = I; \tag 1$

then setting

$B = U - A \ne 0, \tag 2$

we have

$A^\dagger B + B^\dagger A + B^\dagger B = A^\dagger (U - A) + (U - A)^\dagger A + (U - A)^\dagger (U - A)$
$= A^\dagger U - A^\dagger A + U^\dagger A - A^\dagger A + (U^\dagger - A^\dagger)(U - A)$
$=  A^\dagger U - A^\dagger A + U^\dagger A - A^\dagger A + U^\dagger U - U^\dagger A - A^\dagger U + A^\dagger A$
$= A^\dagger U - I +  U^\dagger A - I + I -U^\dagger A - A^\dagger U + I = 0; \tag 3$

so there are indeed *very many* $B \ne 0$ satisfying

$A^\dagger B + B^\dagger A + B^\dagger B = 0, \tag 4$

one $B \ne 0$ for each unitary $U \ne A$.

In fact, all this stuff works with $U = A$, $B = 0$ as well.

***Note Added in Edit, Monday 10 September 2018 12:19 PM PST:***  This in response to our OP Saheb's inquiry, expressed below his comment to this answer, as to whether and what might be necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of $0 \ne B \in \Bbb C^{n \times  n}$ with $A + B$ unitary.  For $n \ge 1$, a sufficient condition is simply the mere existence of unitary $A \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$; for we may choose $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$ yielding $e^{i\theta} \ne 1$; then $U = e^{i\theta} A \ne A$ is unitary as well

$(e^{i\theta}A)^\dagger (e^{i\theta}A) = e^{-i\theta}e^{i\theta}A^\dagger A = A^\dagger A = I; \tag 5$

so setting $B = U - A$ we have $A + B$ unitary; $B$ will then satisfy equation (4) as we have seen; and of course, if $B$ satisfies (4) and $A + B$ is unitary, then

$A^\dagger A = A^\dagger A + A^\dagger B + B^\dagger A + B^\dagger B = (A + B)^\dagger (A + B) = I, \tag 6$

so $A$ must be unitary as well.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Is there any necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of such matrix $B$?

Comment: @Saheb:  I edited my question to address your comment.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you sir for your helpful comment, but still necessary condition is missing.

Comment: @Saheb:  why do you say that?  The ***necessary*** condition(s) being that $B$ satisfy (4) with $A +B$ unitary . . . as I wrote in my ***Note***.

Comment: ok. Got your point. Sir can you suggest me any paper that solves the problem of finding the unitary matrix $A$ which satisfy the equation $AX=B$ where $(X,B)$ are given ,matrices of compatible size.

Comment: @Saheb:  cant think of any *papers*; it's really a pretty basic question which I think can be answered with a general knowledge of matrices.  Note that such $A$ may not even *exist* . . . by the way, what do you think of the idea of accepting my answer, since I'm doing my best to answer your questions . . . just sayin' . . .

Comment: One necessary condition for the existence of such matrix $A$ is that ||X||=||B||.